# Selecting columns using [[]] is very inefficient especially as the size of the dataset increases in python using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance

Created sample data using below function:

```
def create_sample(num_of_rows=1000):
    num_of_rows = num_of_rows # number of records to generate.
    data = {
        'var1' : [random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) for x in range(num_of_rows)],
        'other' : [random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) for x in range(num_of_rows)]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print("Shape : {}".format(df.shape))
    print("Type : \n{}".format(df.dtypes))
    return df
```

```
df = create_sample()
times = []
for i in range(1, 300):
    start = time.time()
    # Make the dataframe 1 column bigger
    df['var' + str(i + 1)] = df['var' + str(i)]
    # Select two columns from the dataframe using double square brackets
    ####################################################
    temp = df[['var' + str(i + 1), 'var' + str(i)]]
    ####################################################
    end = time.time()
    times.append(end - start)
    start = end
plt.plot(times)
print(sum(times))
```

The graph is linear
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmkdB.png)

used pd.concat to select columns, the graph shows peaks at every 100.. why is this so

```
df = create_sample()
times = []
for i in range(1, 300):
    start = time.time()
    # Make the dataframe 1 column bigger
    df['var' + str(i + 1)] = df['var' + str(i)]
    # Select two columns from the dataframe using double square brackets
    ####################################################
    temp = pd.concat([df['var' + str(i + 1)],df['var' + str(i)]], axis=1)
    ####################################################
    end = time.time()
    times.append(end - start)
    start = end
plt.plot(times)
print(sum(times))
```

please ignore indentation.
**From the above we can see that the time taken to select columns using [[]] increases linerly with the size of the dataset.
However, using pd.concat the time does not increase materially. Why increases in every 100 records only.  The above is not obvious
**